# Construct an unbiased estimator for central moments?

Tags: probability

Problem: Construct an unbiased estimator $\hat{\mu_k}$ for $\mu_k=E[X^k]$ for any positive integer k. $\mu=E[X]=0$. (So that we are dealing with central moments.)

(1) show its unbiasedness.
(2) find its variance $var[\hat{\mu_k}]$.
(3) propose an estimator for $var[\hat{\mu_k}]$.
I am learning Hansen's Econometrics on my own. This is a first-year phd econometrics problem. I don't think it's too hard to be solved but the problem requires an 'unbiased' estimation. Does it really need a h-statistic procedure (I've already known its calculation in some R packages and its rationale in the paper where it was invented, but this problem needs a exact math proof instead of a technical result by some R commands, and I don't believe the result is as complex as h-statistics)? Can someone show me the exact expression of this constructed estimator and its the proof of this unbiasedness? Thank you so much!

Comment: h-statistics are unbiased estimators of population central moments and not directly relevant to this problem. The tricky part of this problem is part 3 - if the intention is to provide an unbiased estimator of the variance at 2. The solution is not an h-statistic, but a PolyRaw statistic, which is an unbiased estimator of a product of raw moments. There is a solution posted at mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265424/

Comment: @wolfies Thank you for your help. I know that we can expand the moment as $E[X^k]=E[(X-\mu+\mu)^k]$ so that the answer is a summation of a series of raw moments. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\mu=0$.